# SharedPreferences.Editor is taking too long

Tags: java, android, performance, sharedpreferences

I am fixing a code from an Android Application that is too slow and gets messages like "Skipped 561 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." all the time.

I've tracked what was taking so long and I found out that it was `SharedPreferences.Editor` inside my `clearpreferences` method.

I did this:

```
public void clearpreferences(String name) {
    Log.d("RoTips", "CP I: " + new Date());
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = app.contexto.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Log.d("RoTips", "CP edit: " + new Date());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    Log.d("RoTips", "CP clear: " + new Date());
    editor.clear();
    Log.d("RoTips", "CP commit: " + new Date());
    editor.commit();
    Log.d("RoTips", "CP F: " + new Date());
}
```

and I found out that everything else took less than one sec, but  `"SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();"` took **6MIN**.

So my App keeps waiting for Editor to finish, any idea why is it taking so long?

I don't know if it is related, but those Skipped Frames messages are usually high after this message appears in Debug:

```
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L1
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
```

And before:

```
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 1/32 for video/mp4v-es
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/64 for video/mp4v-es
```

Comment: It should not take that much time. The issue might come due to some other reason. It would be good to analyze the issue if you share the code snippet for calling area of the method.

Comment: 6min is way to long for any operation. 6 seconds even is too long for the SharedPrefs.Editor. Something else is wrong there

Comment: To check where the memory is being eaten up, try using the Android Profiler

Comment: Try clearing shared preferences without assigning the reference to an editor. Like this: 
sharedpreferences.edit().clear().commit()

Comment: How much data are you storing in sharedpreferences?

Comment: @LinuxMasterRace My shared_prefs folder is 4KB, is it too much?